# Outputting a file from a perl script to be read by a bash script

Tags: bash, perl

I have a shell script that calls a perl script to manipulate some data.  Once the Perl script does it's thing it should close and return the data file for the shell (bash) script to then use that file in a function. How do I end my perl script after closing my file?

For a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/environment perl

my $filename = shift @ARGV;

open(my $fh, '+<', $filename) or die "Couldn't Open File";
sort $fh;
close $fh;
```

EDIT: So, Something else may be going wrong here.  The file to be sorted contains one word per line.  If this scripts is working, how do I use the output of it in the bash shell?  I expected:
    perl sort.pl "$filename" > sorted.txt
to save sorted.txt on disk.

Comment: I don't think you need to do any thing special here. The perl script is closing the file. Once it returns, the shell script can work with the file.

Comment: You have posted a perl script/program (the first line #!/usr/bin/environment perl). Care to share the bash script as well?.

Comment: You need to read the data from the file handle, sort it, write it out to somewhere, and then close it.  But why not use the `sort` command.  And it is probably most flexible to have the program write to standard output.

Comment: You can sort a file using Unix/Linux sort command in your shell script. Perl's sort function works on arrays/lists, not on file handles.

Comment: Ahh alright, rookie mistake.  I saw the following as was hoping to do something similar.
    'perl -we 'print sort <>' input.txt > output.txt'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort) function in Perl operates on lists, not file handles. You can use the `<>` operator to read from a filehandle. You also need some output, so [print](http://p3rl.org/print) the results:

```
print sort <$fh>;
```

If you don't do anything more in the Perl script, though, calling the standard `sort` (`/usr/bin/sort` usually) might be easier, cleaner, and more efficient.

Comment: Ahh this is what I was looking for.  Missed the <>.  Brilliant. Works exactly how I wanted it to.  Thank you + everyone.